# VHDL Code for Binary Division bug

Tags: debugging, logic, vhdl, division, circuit

I've written code for a binary divider that takes in an 8 bit dividend, 3 bit divisor, and gives a 5 bit quotient (3 bit remainder). I've literally spent hours trying to fix a bug that gives incorrect results but I haven't been able to identify it. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! I basically get wrong answers for my inputs but I can't figure out why. There is a bus that takes in values and on the first clock cycle where st is 1, the dividend register is loaded. On the second clock cycle after, the divisor register is loaded and the calculation is made for the next three clock cycles.

The V signal is the output to signify that an overflow has occured (the result can't be fit into the five bits of the quotient), my st is the start signal to start the process, sh is the shift signal for the shift register, su is the subtract signal for the subtractor.

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

 entity Divider is
         Port (bus_in: in std_logic_vector(8 downto 0); 
                  St, Clk, reset: in std_logic;
                  Quotient: out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
                  Remainder: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
                  v: out std_logic);
 end Divider;
 architecture Behavioral of Divider is
 signal State, NextState: integer range 0 to 5;
 signal C, Ld1, Ld2, Su, Sh: std_logic;
 signal Divisor: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
 signal Subout: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
 signal Dividend: std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
 begin
         Subout <= Dividend(8 downto 5) - ('0' & divisor);
         C <= not Subout (3);
         Remainder <= Dividend(7 downto 5);
         Quotient <= Dividend(4 downto 0);
State_Graph: process (State, St, C)
 begin
         Ld1 <= '0'; 
         Ld2<='0'; 
         v <= '0'; 
         Sh <= '0'; 
         Su <= '0'; 
         case State is
                 when 0 =>
                         if (St = '1') then 
                                 Ld1 <= '1'; 
                                 NextState <= 1;
                         else 
                                 NextState <= 0; 
                         end if;
                 when 1 =>
                        if (St = '1') then 
                                 Ld2 <= '1'; 
                                 NextState <= 2;
                         else 
                                 Ld2<='1';
                                 NextState <= 2; 
                         end if;
                 when 2 =>
                         if (C = '1') then 
                                 v <= '1'; 
                                 NextState <= 0;
                         else 
                                 Sh <= '1'; 
                                 NextState <= 3; 
                         end if;
                 when 3 | 4  =>
                         if (C = '1') then 
                                 Su <= '1'; 
                                 NextState <= State; 
                         else 
                                 Sh <= '1'; 
                                 NextState <= State + 1; 
                         end if;
                 when 5 =>
                         if (C = '1') then 
                                 Su <= '1'; 
                         end if;

                         NextState <= 0;
         end case;
 end process State_Graph;
 Update: process (Clk)
 begin
         if Clk'event and Clk = '1' then
                 State <= NextState;
                 --if Load = '1' then 
                 --        Dividend <= '0' & bus_in; 
                 --end if;

                 if Ld1 = '1' then
                        Dividend <= '0'&Bus_in(7 downto 0); 
                end if;
                if Ld2 = '1' then
                        Divisor <= Bus_in(2 downto 0); 
                end if;

                if Su = '1' then 
                        Dividend(8 downto 5) <= Subout; 
                        Dividend(0) <= '1'; 
                end if; 
                if Sh = '1' then --94 
                        Dividend <= Dividend(7 downto 0) & '0'; 
                end if;
         end if;
 end process update;
 end Behavioral;
```

Here's my input and outputs:
[Signals]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1w1l.jpg [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfK1r.png)
[image: uploaded image]

The picture shows that my registers for the divisor and dividend is loading correctly. So I think the issue is with the actual division code. The state machine also seems to be working correctly.

Comment: What are the incorrect results? We're not going to read through a wall of code to try and guess where the problem is.

Comment: I don't really have any syntax errors. I'm finding that my code basically spits out incorrect results for my inputs.

Comment: exactly. seeing the inputs and incorrect outputs can tell us a lot.

Comment: Just posted a screenshot of my signals. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Don't write this yourself. You are re-inventing the wheel.

Either write `q <= a / b;`

or use an IP core from your FPGA vendor.